# /usr/bin/ruby2.3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and when I open the console 
and write rails s to start my rails server, following error appears:

`bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby2.3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
but if I use command `bash -l` then use `rails s` every thing works fine.

why do I always need to use `bash -l`command to use `rails s` ? How can I save myself from the overhead of always writing `bash -l`?

Comment: Run awk -F: -v usr=$(whoami) '$1==usr { print $7 }' /etc/passwd and verify that your default shell is /bin/bash. If it isn't change with chsh.

Answer (score 4):

First location your ruby install:

```
which ruby
```

add path to env variables:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ruby-2.6.5/bin
```

Next, location bundle
    which bundle

edit `bundle` first line

```
vi  /usr/local/bin/bundle

#!/usr/bin/ruby2.3
TO
/usr/local/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your title question is that you are attempting to use a distribution of Rails that was made for a different OS, where `/usr/bin/ruby2.3` exists. While you may be able to hack that distribution into working on your OS, it is far simpler to use a version of Rails packaged for your OS specifically. Most Linux OSes have a version in their package repository already.

As for your second question (`bash -l`), you haven't provided enough info to answer it. However, it is highly likely that solving the title question in the way I suggest will solve this problem as well, since the basic problem must be some kind of user environment misconfiguration, which won't happen if you use the OS-provided version of Rails. Bottom line, you should never have to force a Bash login shell that way.